# How do I programmatically add a variable of type Object to an SSIS Package?

Tags: .net, ssis

I am creating an SSIS package programmatically using the SSIS Object model.

I want to add a variable to a package of type Object. But I can't set the Data Type directly as that property is read-only. How do I add a variable of type Object to my package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136082.aspx):

> For a variable ... the DataType value is inferred from the initial
>   value assigned to the variable, and cannot be changed afterward.

So the proper syntax is:

```
Package.Variables.Add("VariableNames", false, "User", new Object());
```

And to assign an initial value:

```
Object o = new Object();
// .. populate o with values in some form ...
Package.Variables.Add("VariableNames", false, "User", o);
```